# How to setup an ADF pipeline that isolates every pipeline run and create its own computer resources?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a simple pipeline in ADF that is triggered by a Logic App every time someone submits a file as response in a Microsoft forms. The pipeline creates a cluster based in a Docker and then uses a Databricks notebook to run some calculations that can take several minutes.

The problem is that every time the pipeline is running and someone submits a new response to the forms, it triggers another pipeline run that, for some reason, will make the previous runs to fail.

The last pipeline will always work fine, but earlier runs will show this error:

> Operation on target "notebook" failed: Cluster **0202-171614-fxvtfurn** does not exist

However, checking the parameters of the last pipeline it uses a different cluster id, **0202-171917-e616dsng** for example.

It seems that for some reason, the computers resources for the first run are relocated in order to be used for the new pipeline run. However, the IDs of the cluster are different.

I have set up the concurrency up to 5 in the pipeline general settings tab, but still getting the same error.

[Concurrency setup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHKEB.png)

Also, in the first connector that looks up for the docker image files I have the concurrency set up to 15, but this won’t fix the issue

[look up concurrency screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k618z.png)

To me, it seems a very simple and common task when it comes to automation and data workflows, but I cannot figure it out.

I really appreciate any help and suggestions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be use an existing pool rather than recreating the pool everytime

[image]